# Can a file's name contain executable code in linux?

Tags: linux, security

This showed up in download folder recently.

The file is empty but the filename was:
''$'\001\331\006''@f2@8'$'\f''@'$'\037\036\006\004''@@@'$'\240\002\240\002\b\003\004\340\002\340\002\340\002\034\034\001\001\004\250\210\002\250\210\002\020\001\005\220\002\220\002\220\002''e'$'\222'

Which bothered me right away because it looks like $unicode_chars, many of them being commands?
001 Start of heading
331 no idea
006 Accept char
\004 End of transmission

At any rate, how does such a file show up on your computer?

Comment: Control characters aren't "executable code". I would be worried if there were escape characters, because some escape sequences can be used to make the terminal emulator send input.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Lesson 1: don't trust arbitrarily dowloaded folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux file names can contain any character, except the null character (\0) and the slash character / (directory separator) [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations). So yes, a file name can contain executable code or any kind of data. It doesn't mean it can be executed, though. The only functions provided by the operating system are file operations, like opening the file, directory listing, etc. To be able to execute the code it must be inside the file, not on its name.

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations

Answer (score 0):

> This showed up in download folder recently.

You (not your computer) is responsible for your downloads!

> At any rate, how does such a file show up on your computer?

Smells like your computer (or the computer from which you downloaded carelessly) has been compromised by some [vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing)) or [cyberattack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberattack), or that a very buggy program (with [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)) has been carelessly run.

Another possibility is a severe hardware problem, e.g. a dying hard disk or SSD, faulty RAM, cosmic rays, a careless power outage, which corrupted some [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system).

Consider using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [gdb(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html), [fsck(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fsck.8.html), [dmesg(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html) to investigate more.

Backup carefully your important data before.